# Determine sequence with generating function $(2x-3)^3$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

Determine the sequence associated to the following generating function: $(2x-3)^3$

I know that the sequence $\left(\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}, \ldots\right)$ has the generating function $(1+x)^3$ so I know that this sequence must be similar to the one I am looking for. But I am not sure how to manage the rest. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence determined by a power series $\sum_{n\ge 0}a_nx^n$ is simply the sequence $\langle a_0,a_1,a_2,\ldots\rangle$. Expanding $(2x-3)^3$, we get

$$-27+54x-36x^2+8x^3\;,$$

which corresponds to the sequence $\langle -27,54,-36,8,0,0,0,\ldots\rangle$.

Comment: I don't think this is right. According to your method, the sequence corresponding to $(1+x)^3$ would be $(1, 1, 0, 0, 0,...)$ and that is false

Comment: @fdez: You’ve apparently misunderstood what I wrote, which does **not** imply that the associated sequence is $\langle 1,1,0,0,0,\ldots\rangle$. $(1+x)^3$ is not a power series in $x$ as it stands; it becomes one only after you multiply it out to get $1+3x+3x^2+x^3$, at which point you see that the associated sequence is $\langle 1,3,3,1,0,0,0,\ldots\rangle$.

Comment: Ok I see the problem now. I had misplaced the parentheses. It's not $(2x+3^3)$ has I had written, it is $(2x+3)^3$. Sorry for the typo

Comment: @fdez: Okay; give me a minute to rewrite it.

Comment: Why you closed my question while it's not duplicate??

Answer (score 0):

The "generating function" for the series "$a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3,\cdot\cdot\cdot$" is the function, f(x), that corresponds to the power series $a_0+ a_1x+ a_2x^2+ a_3x^3+ \cdot\cdot\cdot$. In this case the function **is** a polynomial, $(2x- 3)^3= 8x^3- 36x^2+ 54x- 27$.   Trivially then the sequence is -27, 54. -36, 8, 0, 0, 0, ...